# Network support when emulating firmware with QEMU

Tags: firmware, qemu, networking, emulation

Continuing from this question:
[Firmware analysis and file system extraction?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2704/firmware-analysis-and-file-system-extraction)

I am trying to run the QNap firmware using QEmu. I have basically the same 
firmware as is used in the question above.

My QEMU command is as follows:

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel bzImage -initrd initrd.boot -m 2048 -smp 8
```

This works and I get the QNap login page.

But there is one thing that I cannot get to work (I tried lots of things...), that is: How to get networking up and running? There is only the local loopback interface when I use the ifconfig command. There should be a default NIC for qemu VM's, but I only see it on startup when simply running the qemu-system-x86_64 command.
What can I do to get this VM running with networking configured, so I can perform some tests with it?

Comment: I now also have the same firmware running in a Virtual Box VM, but also here I do not know how to add the network.

Comment: Try port redirection -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking#User_mode_networking

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-net` argument `-net nic,model=rtl8139`. Of course replace `rtl8139` with your network device model (e1000, i82551, i82557b, ...)

Further explanations are found on this [Wiki Documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Devices/Network)